# Setting Ubuntu server as router can't access internet

Tags: networking, iptables, router

Im trying to simulate a network (router, firewall, PCs and server) with several virtual machines running Ubuntu Server. I have followed several tutorials, questions on this froum and so on but I can't get it working.

**My setup**

-> One virtual machine that is suppoused to be the router with 2 network interfaces

1. enp0s3 -> connected with my machine (where I have internet)
2. enp0s8 -> connected into a private network

-> One virtual machine that is suppoused to be the firewall with 3 network interfaces

3. enp0s3 -> connected in the same private network
4. the other 2 are for server and pc but not using them right now

**So far I've got**

/etc/network/interfaces device one (router)

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp


auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
      address 10.20.0.1
      netmask 255.255.192.0
      network 10.20.0.0
      broadcast 10.20.63.255
      gateway 10.20.0.1
```

iptable

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT) 
target         prot   opt  source            destination
MASQUERADE     ALL    --   anywhere          anywhere
```

I have aswell uncommented the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

/etc/network/interfaces device two (firewall)

(I just copied the one that is connected with the router)

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
         address 10.20.0.2
         netmask 255.255.192.0
         network 10.20.0.0
         broadcast 10.20.63.255
         gateway 10.20.0.1

.....
```

iptable is empty in this one (Im not sure if I have to set anything)

Router has connection with internet, both devices communicate with each other (ping).

**My problem**

I'm trying to Access google (ping 8.8.8.8) with my firewall device but it says:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

What am I missing? Why can't I Access the internet in my second device?

P.S: I have both adapters set in the same network in VirtualBox

Comment: The iptables output does not give enough information. If you have only masquerading without other iptables settings, that is not enough.

Comment: its the only one I have, what else do I need?

Comment: I am not 100% sure any more, but I think you have to take care of established and related connections. Take a look here https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO/ and here http://www.billauer.co.il/ipmasq-html.html. Next is more detailed tutorial, where I learned iptables from https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html. The data on iptables, you have provided does not give information about interfaces. Provide configuration or commands not just the part of output.